# Being two “things” at once

Tags: obscure-terms

I am looking for an old/obscure term meaning to possess simultaneous or concurrent ways of being. Specifically, this term could apply to someone who holds multiple jobs. 
Thanks so much!

Comment: [**portfolio worker**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/portfolio-worker) - *a person who works for several different companies or organizations at the same time*.

Comment: The expression 'wearing different hats' applies to the situation. **wear a different hat**: to hold or function in a different position or role simultaneously.
_Few know that the renowned actress wears a different hat as an accomplished neuroscientist._ [[Farlex Dictionary of Idioms](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/wear+a+different+hat)]

Answer (score 1):

**Johannes factotum** ("Johnny do-it-all")
or less obscure **Jack of all Trades**.

The first thing that came to mind was

[Jack of all trades](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_of_all_trades,_master_of_none)

It's not obscure, but it's quite old all the same. From Wikipedia:

> "Jack of all trades, master of none" is a figure of speech used in
>   reference to a person who has dabbled in many skills, rather than
>   gaining expertise by focusing on one. The shortened version "a jack of
>   all trades" is often a compliment for a person who is good at fixing
>   things, and has a very good broad knowledge.
> In 1612, the
>   English-language version of the phrase appeared in the book "Essays
>   and Characters of a Prison" by English writer Geffray Mynshul
>   (Minshull), originally published in 1618, and probably based on
>   the author's experience while held at Gray's Inn, London, when
>   imprisoned for debt.

In the same Wikipedia article they speak of *Johannes factotum*, which is not used today and I personally had never heard of before. I thought the Shakespeare reference was cute, and if it's obscure you're looking for this might fit the bill.

> In Elizabethan English the quasi-New Latin term Johannes factotum
>   ("Johnny do-it-all") was sometimes used, with the same negative
>   connotation that "Jack of all trades" sometimes has today. The term
>   was famously used by Robert Greene in his 1592 booklet Greene's
>   Groats-Worth of Wit, in which he dismissively refers to
>   actor-turned-playwright William Shakespeare with this term, the first
>   published mention of the writer.

Comment: *Jack off all trades* implies a diverse skillset, but it doesn't imply holding multiple jobs simultaneously.

Comment: @nnnnnn Did you actually say "jack _off_"? ;-)

Comment: I’ve never heard anyone actually use the _Johannes_ bit, but it’s worth noting that a ***factotum*** in itself has none of the negative connotations of a jack of all trades – it is a very positive thing. It doesn’t imply holding multiple jobs, though, just doing any- and everything in one job.

Comment: @Cascabel - Must have been an auto-correct error ;-)

Comment: @Jim Whatever....it gave me a chuckle on a bad evening. Thanks. On the other hand...in NY we used to call an idiot "
Jack off all trades"

Comment: @Cascabel - The implication was that the phone Has learned what is most often typed over time and has helpfully attempted to correct It... :-)

Comment: @Cascabel - Oops. Typo, and unfortunately can't be edited now.

Comment: @nnnnnn ...perhaps a Freudian slip?

Answer (score 1):

There's a few where they have one boss but are tasked with multiple jobs under that boss to do whatever needs doing.

- Guy/Gal Friday
- Dogsbody
- Gofer (that's a bit more modern)
- Factotum

Some that imply multiple skill sets

- Jack of all trades
- Polymath
- Dilettante

For holding multiple jobs all I can think of is "Moonlighter".